# Rewrite php is not working with index.php | index.html

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

My .htaccess really works well, when I have a page like domain.com/hello/test.php it shows as domain.com/hello/test
But the problem is when I have a index.php it show normaly like that domain.com and in folder html is the index.php but now you must go domain.com/index so I want to exclude index.php and index.html files from the RewriteEngine

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: because `!-f` means if file does not exit , so when you enter domain it looks for `index.php` and finds it so file exists and condition doesn't become true . you may just use rewriterule if you want all to redirect